# Check login at the beginning of a WordPress page

Tags: wordpress

I know user login can be checked using `is_user_logged_in()` function. But I am trying to use something like `<?php require_once("logincheck.php"); ?>` at the beginning of page.

So that it won't need to check user logged_in in every function of the page. So far I am not being able to do this.

Comment: Why you are not using init action he will do same what you need and with that you do not required to do creat a different file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init action perform exact your requirement.

```
add_action(‘init’,’usercheck’);

 function usercheck(){
 if(is_user_logged_in()){
  // put your logic for login user
 }else{
  //put your logic for non login user
 }
```

Comment: now can i put add_action(‘init’,’usercheck’); before each function

Comment: Put in function.php file and apply your logic if you are having manny function for logged in user than create a file and include it in my comment area. Read comments in my code.

Comment: I have a form method=post which is redirecting to an external side.I need to check logged inside this from.But can't

Comment: So now include that file in if conditions and put return in else your work is done..

Comment: thnks for your help